# Javascript not displaying in Webview after page loaded

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I am loading an internal webpage from assets. When onPageFinished fires, I asynchronously request data from a server and inject the response data into the page using jQuery. From time to time the webpage is blank as if the javascript never executed. The server response data is there and should display. Should I be calling webview.postInvalidate(); in the thread that injects the response data? I think the problem is the View as the data is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly enable Javascript in your WebView: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setJavaScriptEnabled(boolean)

Comment: I should have specified that js is enabled.